BQL installation issue in VSCode
Referring to this How get BQL (bLOOMBERG) query from python
I followed all steps and copy pasted the packages in my .venv folder, under lib/site_packages. I do not have an anaconda distribution as per their instructions though.
I see the bql package in VSCode Explorer in the same folder as any other packages I normally use (e.g. numpy) as I always use that environment. It has the ini file etc.
But if I try import bql, it tells me it cannot find it.
Did anybody have same issue and can help me understand why it cannot load the package?
Please note I cannot use pip install as I need to copy it from BQuant
Thank you very much
Tried: steps as of How get BQL (bLOOMBERG) query from python but saved in venv instead of anaconda3 as I use VSCode
Expectation: import bql works fine
Outcome: import bql can't find package
